# How to determine the Standard Matrix from these Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have these vectors here below[image]

Is there a linear transformation L such that L (u1) = u2 and L (u3) = u4? If yes:

How many such L are there? Enter the Standard matrix for such an image L. If the answer is no: Explain

I know that there exist a Linear Transformation inifite linear Transformations but i don't know how to form the Standard Matrix here?

I know that the Standard Matrix is (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) but i don't know how to insert the Standard Matrix in this case somebody how know how to get the Standard Matrix out of this??

Comment: Your question highly miss context. What is $L$ ? I guess that the $u_i$ are in $\mathbb R^4$. Does $L:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^4$ ? or does it $L$ is from a proper subspace ? (the answer to "how many are they" highly depend on that).

Comment: @Surb I think span {u1,u3} form some basis?